# How can I prevent automatic unit cycling?

Tags: civilization-6

Military units cycle automatically once they've finished taking an action, but there's a notable delay and more often than not it just results in me clicking on the wrong tile on the map. It's really annoying, and either forces me to accept the mistake or reload a previous save.

Is there any way to turn this automatic unit cycling off?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can turn off automated unit cycling by editing the `UserOptions.txt` file, which if  you're on windows should be located inside of `my games\Sid Meier's Civilization VI`. Open that file with a text editor and then edit the following line (should be line  60):

```
AutoUnitCycle 1
```

You want to change that *1* to a *0*, like so:

```
AutoUnitCycle 0
```

Hopefully this will eventually be added to the User Interface,  but for now you'll just need to edit this file.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/58s9hr/psa_you_can_turn_off_unit_cycling_in_civ_6/)

Comment: You say 1 to a 2, but your example shows a 0?

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade That's because I'm dumb, and it should say a 0 to a 1. Fixed.